# Hibernate dynamic @where clause workaround

Tags: hibernate, dynamic, where-clause

Is there is any way or workaround, by which we can pass value to Hibernate @where.

I dont need to write the Criteria or any thing else.

Just wanted dynamic @where by any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

No. Annotations can only have constant value.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not possible to do with annotations. You didn't ask any question regarding your real problem which you are trying to solve.

Comment: I have a Student Table where I keep student records academic year wise. I just wanted display current academic year students records by only changing code at one place...regardless of making query where clause at everywhere...Please help...!!